# Problem with \@makecaption

Tags: errors

I can compile a .tex file on my own system but when I transfer the folder to an external server and run the same file, I get the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: \@makecaption undefined.
```

followed by a litany of hyperref warnings.

Is this a problem with the caption package that is installed on the external server? What can I do to track the issue?

My preamble is:

```
% mn2esample.tex
%
% v2.1 released 22nd May 2002 (G. Hutton)
%
% The mnsample.tex file has been amended to highlight
% the proper use of LaTeX2e code with the class file
% and using natbib cross-referencing. These changes
% do not reflect the original paper by A. V. Raveendran.
% 
% Previous versions of this sample document were
% compatible with the LaTeX 2.09 style file mn.sty
% v1.2 released 5th September 1994 (M. Reed)
% v1.1 released 18th July 1994
% v1.0 released 28th January 1994

\documentclass[useAMS,usenatbib]{mn2e}

% If your system does not have the AMS fonts version 2.0 installed, then
% remove the useAMS option.
%
% useAMS allows you to obtain upright Greek characters.
% e.g. \umu, \upi etc.  See the section on "Upright Greek characters" in
% this guide for further information.
%
% If you are using AMS 2.0 fonts, bold math letters/symbols are available
% at a larger range of sizes for NFSS release 1 and 2 (using \boldmath or
% preferably \bmath).
%
% The usenatbib command allows the use of Patrick Daly's natbib.sty for
% cross-referencing.
%
% If you wish to typeset the paper in Times font (if you do not have the
% PostScript Type 1 Computer Modern fonts you will need to do this to get
% smoother fonts in a PDF file) then uncomment the next line
% \usepackage{Times}

%%%%% AUTHORS - PLACE YOUR OWN MACROS HERE %%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{units}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{units}
%\usepackage{deluxetable}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ulem}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
```

Comment: you haven't given enough information to really help, but `\@makecaption` is defined in `article` class and several others, perhaps you are using a class that does not define it, how are we to guess?

Comment: The class you're using is incompatible with `caption` and `subfigure` (the latter is obsolete, by the way). Do you *really* need to use `mn2e`?

Comment: The issue is that this tex file runs very well on my own system, but when I try running it on a server, it doesn't compile at all and reports this error. Is it because the server has outdated files. I am aware that subfigure is obsolete.

Comment: @stars83clouds: See [Which package version am I using?](http://goo.gl/sBfU5X) That way one can figure out what is up-to-date/not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because according to the OPs answer posted below the problem was caused by `\usepackage{caption}`.

Comment: According to https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mnras the mn2e document class is deprecated. But as already stated, the `caption` package is incompatible to this document class (or its successor) anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the `\usepackage{caption}` line in the preamble and it runs without error.

Comment: This is the author!